# Trying to understand how jekyll works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll

I have a website that is written in another framework, but it is a site that can be converting into a static site I'm thinking.

It has categories, and content associated to categories.

Would jekyll be a good candidate for this?  My site has basically a simple template.

does it also have a concept of categories?

Does it re-generate lists also?

I wish there was a step by step tutorial on how it is used.

Comment: <http://jekyllbootstrap.com/lessons/jekyll-introduction.html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does it also have a concept of categories?

Yes, you can include [categories](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/YAML-Front-Matter) in posts in Jekyll.

> Does it re-generate lists also?

Do you mean, re-generate the list of posts in a category? Jekyll does expose a [`site.categories` variable](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Template-Data) which contains the site's categories and all posts in each category, but you'll have to create your own template for outputting this data.

Answer (score 0):

There's a wiki entry showing how Jekyll works and [you can find it here](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/How-Jekyll-works). I wrote it, so if you have any questions, please do ask. Also, be aware that this is meant for version 0.12.1, which isn't compatible with 1.0.0.beta2.

```
Does it also have a concept of categories? Does it re-generate lists also?
```

Yes, it has the both the concept of categories and tags. It can generate lists of basically everything you want -- blog posts from the whole site, from categories, from tags, from specific dates or range of dates, etc. You just need to use the Liquid tags correctly.

```
I wish there was a step by step tutorial on how it is used.
```

There [this simple guide in the wiki](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Usage). Also, you can read [Building Static Sites with Jekyll](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/building-static-sites-with-jekyll/) and [an introduction from Jekyll Boostrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/lessons/jekyll-introduction.html).